# What is this small plant with tiny yellow flowers?

Tags: identification

This small plant with tiny yellow flowers is collected in South-Central Europe. Found in a field.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it is *Oxalis dillenii*, a North-American species which is invading Europe.

Some info in French (or German): https://www.infoflora.ch/fr/flore/oxalis-dillenii.html#info . So it doesn't have stolons, but still long stems.

These yellow flowering *Oxalis* likes dry and sunny places (*O. corniculata* is a European species, but it is smaller, and less flowers). Most of them are weeds that likes "forgotten" pots.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be Wood Sorrel (Oxalis acetosella) the seed pods are a favorite nibble of my chickens. A minor potherb and in small amounts, it is edible for humans as well.

Comment: Oxalis, yes, acetosella certainly not: the plant in question has *yellow* flowers while wood sorrel has white petals with sometimes a purple tinge. And “in a field” is also untypical for wood sorrel, which prefers the dappled shade of forests.

Comment: I agree, certainly not O. acetosella but rather O. dillenii (Southern Wood Sorrel) as Giacomo answered.